# How to disable sorting element under cdkDropListGroup in angular CDK?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I was trying to implementing draging and dropping in both direction using angular CDK and Grid Layout. So i am keeping the elements under cdkDropListGroup to connect the all cdkDropList. Now i want to disable sorting among the elements. I tried using cdkDropListSortingDisabled but it's not working. Is their any way to do it?

```
<div cdkDropListGroup class="grid-layout-styles example-list">
    <div [ngStyle]="getStyle(item)"  cdkDropList cdkDropListSortingDisabled
         *ngFor="let item of items" [id]="item.id">
         <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>{{item.title}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well it should work, have you seen the example: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/examples#cdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting
Whats the difference compared to your scenario?

Comment: What happens if replacing `cdkDropList ` to `[cdkDropList]="items"`?

Comment: @N.F. It's giving error " Can't bind to 'cdkDropList' since it isn't a known property of 'div'."

Comment: @Zerotwelve
Actually in the following example "Available Items" and 
"Shopping basket" represents two cdkList groups. And under both
cdkList group there are multiple item.

But in my case each element represent a cdkList item.
You can see in the material that the loop is not with the cdkDropList.
It's inside the cdkDropList. But in my case the loop is with the cdkDropList.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259720/error-when-using-cdkdroplistdata-in-angular-gives-me-cant-bind-to-cdkdroplistd